# Searching for a specific structure in a string

Tags: html, python-3.x

I am working on a project where I want to transform a nwodkram file to a HTML file. In nwodkram an URL is given on the form

```
[www.stackoverflow.com](This is StackOverflow)
```

which in HTML corresponds to

```
<a href='www.stackoveflow.com'>This is StackOverflow<\a>.
```

I could do something like this:

```
def parser_nwodkram(text):
    string = list(text)

    counter = 0     # Count number of characters in string

    for char in string:
        if char == '[':
            sq_par_0 = counter      # Location of square parenthesis 0
        if char == ']':
            if 'sq_par_0' in locals():
                url = "".join(string[sq_par_0+1:counter])
        if char == '(':
            if 'url' in locals():
                par_0 = counter
        if char == ')':
            if 'par_0' in locals():
                url_ref = r"<a href='{}'>{}<\a>".format(\
                          "".join(string[par_0+1:counter]), url)
            string[counter] = url_ref
            del string[sq_par_0:counter]

        counter += 1  

    return "".join(string)
```

but I want to do it more elegant and efficient, is there a way of searching for a certain structure in a string, in this case

```
[...](...)?
```

Comment: You really should use regexp see: https://regexr.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this using regex. You can create re groups in `re.search` for this and get both elements. Example:

```
>>> a = '[www.stackoverflow.com](This is StackOverflow)'
>>> import re
>>> match = re.search('(\[.*?\])(\(.*?\))',a)
>>> match.group()
'[www.stackoverflow.com](This is StackOverflow)'
>>> match.group(1)
'[www.stackoverflow.com]'
>>> match.group(2)
'(This is StackOverflow)'
>>>
```

For your problem, it would simply be like:

```
import re
def parser_nwodkram(text):
    match = re.search('\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)',text)
    url_ref = "<a href='%s'>%s</a>" % (match.group(1), match.group(2))
    print url_ref

parser_nwodkram('[www.stackoverflow.com](This is StackOverflow)')
```

Output:

```
<a href='www.stackoverflow.com'>This is StackOverflow</a>
```

Further you can implement proper exception handling for regex (AttributeError here) to handle situations where text is not given properly

Answer (score 0):

You can always use python's built-in regexps from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)